# Error en ejercicio python listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, funciones, arraylist

Buen día, tengo un inconveniente con el siguiente ejercicio donde se me pide lo siguiente:

> Escriba una función que reciba un string s y un número n como parámetros y retorne el mismo string s pero sin el elemento en el índice n.
> Por ejemplo, si s es "Hasta luego" y n es 3, entonces tu función debe retornar "Hasa luego".
> Hint: cuidado con aquellos casos en los que se tenga que eliminar un elemento de los bordes.

mi código es el siguiente:

```python
def remover_enesimos(s,n):

  s = list(s)

  del s[n]

  s = "".join(s)

  return s

 print (remover_enesimos(input("Escribe tu frase o palabra: "), int(input("Escribe el índice: "))))
```

[image: Ejemplo error]
mi error radica en lo que muestra la imagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error no tiene nada que ver con que el ejercicio está mal. Lo que te sugiero cuando trabajes con python es que tengas MUCHO cuidado, pero que **MUCHO** cuidado con la **[indentación](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Su_primer_programa_en_Python/Sangrado_(indentado)_de_c%C3%B3digo)**. Python no tiene corchetes ni paréntesis para marcar bloques de código, todo depende de la indentación, y esta ha de ser *uniforme* en **TODO** el código (Y por lo general, se indenta a 4 espacios, pero lo hagas como lo hagas SIEMPRE debes usar los mismos espacios):

```
def remover_enesimos(s, n):
    s = list(s)
    del s[n]
    s = "".join(s)
    return s


print(remover_enesimos(input("Escribe tu frase o palabra: "), int(input("Escribe el índice: "))))
```

El error estaba en que había 1 espacio antes del print, lo he eliminado y he indentado todo correctamente.

Edit:

En el enunciado no pone nada de que tenga que ser con listas así que si te interesa, te dejo cómo hacerlo usando los índices de python:

```
def remover_enesimos(s, n):
    return s[:n] + s[n+1:]
```

Basicamente devuelve la suma de la cadena entera hasta el carácter `n` y la cadena desde el carácter `n+1` hasta el final.

Los parámetros que **no** pones en el selector del índice significan:

- **Primer parámetro --> [:n]:** coge todo desde el principio hasta n
- **Segundo parámetro --> [n:]:** coge desde n hasta el final
- **Ningún parámetro --> [:]:** Coge todo
  Incluso puedes pasar parámetros en negativo, si quieres saber más aquí tienes un [buen artículo (en inglés)](https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/) sobre el uso de índices en python.

Comment: gracias por el consejo de indentación, ahora el compilador arroja:
 "Error on line 8:
    print(remover_enesimos(input("Escribe tu frase o palabra: "), int(input("Escribe el índice: "))))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente tanto en mi máquina como online: https://repl.it/repls/MintyHoneydewProtools
 Qué usas para trabajar con python? Hay muchos editores que tienen problemas con python y los errores EOF son muy comunes por ejemplo con Sublime, pero no significan que haya ningún error en el código